# BulkCopy tarda demasiado con 100 registros C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

Tengo un archivo de Excel que paso a una `DataTable` y después a un `DataReader` (viendo ejemplos en internet decide esto), la cosa es que agarro esa `DataTable` (la primera), la paso a otra (Solo para verificar que los datos sean correctos), tomo la DT la convierto a DR y la ingreso, este es el método:

```
//INSERTA CLIENTE MASIVO
        public string InsertBulkCliente(DataTable dt)
        {
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();

            dc.ColumnName = "Cedula";
            dc.DataType = typeof(long);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Nombres";
            dc.DataType = typeof(string);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Apellido1";
            dc.DataType = typeof(string);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Apellido2";
            dc.DataType = typeof(string);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Edad";
            dc.DataType = typeof(int);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Tel1";
            dc.DataType = typeof(long);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Tel2";
            dc.DataType = typeof(long);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Tel3";
            dc.DataType = typeof(long);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Tel4";
            dc.DataType = typeof(long);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Direccion";
            dc.DataType = typeof(string);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Correo";
            dc.DataType = typeof(string);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "FechaAlta";
            dc.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Callable";
            dc.DataType = typeof(bool);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Asignable";
            dc.DataType = typeof(bool);
            dt3.Columns.Add(dc);

            foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    DataRow rw = dt3.NewRow();
                    rw["Cedula"] = Convert.ToInt64(dtRow["Cedula"]);
                    rw["Nombres"] = dtRow["Nombres"];
                    rw["Apellido1"] = dtRow["Apellido1"];
                    rw["Apellido2"] = dtRow["Apellido2"];
                    rw["Edad"] = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow["Edad"]);
                    rw["Tel1"] = Convert.ToInt64(dtRow["Tel1"]);
                    rw["Tel2"] = Convert.ToInt64(dtRow["Tel2"]);
                    rw["Tel3"] = Convert.ToInt64(dtRow["Tel3"]);
                    rw["Tel4"] = Convert.ToInt64(dtRow["Tel4"]);
                    rw["Direccion"] = dtRow["Direccion"];
                    rw["Correo"] = dtRow["Correo"];
                    rw["FechaAlta"] = Convert.ToDateTime(dtRow["FechaAlta"]);
                    rw["Callable"] = dtRow["Callable"];
                    rw["Asignable"] = dtRow["Asignable"];
                    dt3.Rows.Add(rw);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "Error de Mapeo Datos: " + ex.Message.ToString();
                }

            }

            DataTableReader reader = dt3.CreateDataReader();

            using (SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Clientes.Clientes";
                    SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
                    //bulkInsert.BatchSize = dt3.Rows.Count;
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = dt3.Rows.Count;
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                    //bulkInsert.NotifyAfter = dt3.Rows.Count;
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Cedula", "Cedula");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Nombres", "Nombres");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Apellido1", "Apellido1");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Apellido2", "Apellido2");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Edad", "Edad");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tel1", "Tel1");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tel2", "Tel2");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tel3", "Tel3");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tel4", "Tel4");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Direccion", "Direccion");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Correo", "Correo");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("FechaAlta", "FechaAlta");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Callable", "Callable");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Asignable", "Asignable");
                    try
                    {
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                        return "Datos Ingresado correctamente!!!";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.Write(e.Message);
                        return "Error de insercion de datos: " + e.Message.ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Si debugueo y detengo el código justo antes del:

```
using (SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
```

La inserción a la base de datos no tarda ni 2 segundos al darle "Continuar", pero si quito el `breakpoint` la inserción de esos 100 registros tarda mas de 6 minutos en completarse (cuando he leído que un millón de registros a veces tarda 40 segundos), me pueden ayudar a saber que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

EL tipo de bloqueo que especificas a nivel de tabla puede estar ralentizando tu bulkcopy y es más puede estár ocasionando deadlocks a nivel de SQL Server, por lo que deberías utilizar el predeterminado bloqueo a nivel de filas y probablemente también resulte deseable mantener todo dentro de una transacción

Cambia el último parámetro a  **SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction**

```
SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction);
```

Además, en estos bloques abres 2 conexiones y creas dos objetos SqlBulkCopy, de modo que el objeto bulkInsert no lo utilizas realmente pero lo conectas por medio de un connectionString.

```
    //1er conexión, objeto connection
    using (SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Clientes.Clientes";
            //2da conexión, objeto no utilizado
            SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
            //bulkInsert.BatchSize = dt3.Rows.Count;
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = dt3.Rows.Count;
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
```

Modifica lo siguiente:

```
    using (SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Clientes.Clientes";

            bulkCopy.BatchSize = dt3.Rows.Count;
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Cedula", "Cedula");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Nombres", "Nombres");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Apellido1", "Apellido1");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Apellido2", "Apellido2");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Edad", "Edad");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tel1", "Tel1");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tel2", "Tel2");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tel3", "Tel3");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tel4", "Tel4");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Direccion", "Direccion");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Correo", "Correo");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("FechaAlta", "FechaAlta");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Callable", "Callable");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Asignable", "Asignable");
            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                return "Datos Ingresado correctamente!!!";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
                return "Error de insercion de datos: " + e.Message.ToString();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No funciono, sigue dando el mismo tiempo para insertar

Comment: Reinicia tu servicio MSSQLSVR, para descartar posibles deadlocks

Comment: sigue tardando aun cuando reinicie el servicio

Comment: Por favor prueba la edición de mi respuesta. no me había fijado que tienes al menos dos conexiones abiertas y dos objetos bulkcopy. Solo necesitas uno de cada tipo.

Comment: Vieras que al revisar el codigo tambien note que tenia 2 conexiones, lo he corregido como tu ejemplo y sigue igual, de hecho en ocasiones no dura ni un segundo pero cuando lo abro otro dia o mas tarde ese dia vuelve a durar 5 minutos